# HTTP to HTTPS Apache redirect doesn't work when used with other redirects

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, opencart

I have been asked to help with an OpenCart 1.5.6.1 installation on shared hosting with some redirection requirements.

Some of the redirects were already present and I'm not sure if they are required for OpenCart.

The new requirement is to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

When I add a command to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS the browser reports an error that redirects are not working correctly. This command has always worked on other sites before. I am guessing that there is a conflict with one or more of the other redirect commands.

These are the existing redirect commands with the comments on what they do:

```sh
# Redirect oldexample.co.uk to example.co.uk
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)oldexample\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The directive I add which causes redirects to break is:

```sh
#Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Why does this not work and how can get all of these redirect requirements to work together?

**Additional requested information:**

The result of `curl --head http://example.co.uk`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 18:17:10 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.51 (Unix)
location: https://www.example.co.uk/
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The result of `curl --head http://www.example.co.uk`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 19:20:47 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.51 (Unix)
location: https://www.example.co.uk/
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The result of `curl --head https://www.example.co.uk` is

```
HTTP/2 301 
date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 19:20:54 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.51 (Unix)
location: https://www.example.co.uk/
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

This I suppose is where a redirection loop occurs.

Output of `print_r( $_SERVER, true)` HTTP_ indices:

```
[HTTPS] => on
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en;q=0.5
[HTTP_DNT] => 1
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST] => document
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE] => navigate
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE] => none
[HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER] => ?1
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
[HTTP_TE] => trailers
[HTTP_HOST] => www.example.co.uk (changed)
[HTTP_COOKIE] => language=en; currency=GBP; PHPSESSID=(removed)
[HTTP_X_PROTO] => SSL
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
```

Comment: Where in that .htaccess file did you add that new rule?  Did you add it above or below the other rules?   Are there any subdirectories with their own .htaccess files involved?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I've tried adding it above and below the existing rules but always after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Are you using a load balancer or CDN that is handling HTTPS for you?   (As opposed to it being configured in Apache)?

Comment: No, to the load balancer or CDN. No other .htaccess files besides one to create a password-protected directory.

Comment: Instead of testing with a browser, can you test with [curl](https://curl.se/) on the command line?   `curl --head http://example.com`  That would eliminate browser caching as a source of your problems.   Please [edit] your question with the results from `curl`

Comment: Since you are using PHP, dump the contents of the `$_SERVER` superglobal when accessing the site over HTTPS and add this to your question.

Comment: @Fabian That is really no different than the rule given in the question (in fact, it's "worse", since it is missing the `R` and `L` flags). If this rule is triggering a "redirect-loop" (as suggested in the question) then it's because the preceding _condition_ is always successful, ie. the `HTTPS` server variable is not set as expected.

Comment: The response according to your CURL output is as if you don't have the `#Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` rule in place? There is no "redirect error" here (as reported by the browser)? The redirect to HTTPS in your first test is presumably the result of the non-www to www redirect present in your first code block. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite, Sorry I wasn't thinking clearly. :-)

Comment: @MrWhite what were you looking for in $_SERVER? I don't want to post the full dump. Thanks.

Comment: Mainly the array indices that start `HTTP_` (eg. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` etc.) that represent HTTP request headers. Also `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` - although this doesn't necessarily represent the Apache server variable of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [HTTP_X_PROTO] => SSL
> ```

The presence of the `X-Proto` HTTP request header would seem to imply you are behind some kind of proxy, that is perhaps managing the secure connection. Although the use of `X-Proto` is (very) non-standard, particularly with the given value.

Try the following immediately after your non-www to www redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Proto} !=SSL
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache and test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

Comment: I've no idea about proxies but that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain (in simple terms, if possible) why this prevented the original redirects from working?

Comment: There is some piece of hardware like a load balancer sitting in front of your web server.  It has the ssl certs installed on it and is handling the https then passing the request to the web server over http.  It lets the web server know that the original request was https by adding that header.  Your original rules were testing that the web server itself was receiving https requests, which must not actually be happening.

Comment: ... so the `HTTPS` Apache server variable in the `RewriteCond` directive is always `off`, which results in a redirect loop. Not to be confused with the `HTTPS` index in the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal array, which is generated by PHP and does not necessarily correspond directly with the `HTTPS` Apache server variable. `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` could represent an _environment_ variable of the same name. If so, then you may also be able to use `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on` instead. @authentictech